# updating single items in useState hooks from a Picker

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, picker, use-state

So I have a **DropDownPicker** that I imported from `react-native-dropdown-picker`,

I want to update a single item in a mapped state:

```
const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState({Country: '', Name: ''});
```

The picker code is:

```
<DropDownPicker items={[    //JSON import
                                        {label: 'USA'},
                                        {label: 'India'},
                                        {label: 'Germany'},
                                        {label: 'France'},
                                        {label: 'Israel'},
                                    ]}
                placeholder="Country"
                containerStyle={styles.pickerHeight}
                style={styles.picker}
                dropDownStyle={styles.pickerDrop}
                onChangeItem = {(item) => {
                    // ------------------- here I want to update 'Country'
                }}
            />
```

I've tried: `setCurrentUser({Country: item.label})` but obviously it caused the `Name` property to be deleted.

What is the correct way to update a single item in the state without losing data?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the spread operator to first get your current user's data, then simply overwrite the country: `setCurrentUser(currentUser => ({ ...currentUser, Country: item.label }))`

Comment: That was exactly what I needed. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
setCurrentUser(prevState => {
    return {
        ...prevState,
        Country: <new_country>
    }
})
```

Comment: Sorry. I didn't notice that someone already helped :))